# No module named 'cv2' anaconda

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, opencv, tensorflow, anaconda

Создал нейронную сеть в виртуальной среде через anaconda. Запустил. Все работает. Сохранил модель. Пробую запустить повторно. Получаю ошибку:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

и т.д. по всем остальным подключенным библиотекам. Что делать? Библиотеки подключены верно и работают при запуске файла с обучением модели в этой же среде. Может попробовать заново создать вирт.среду ?

Команды не помогли:

> conda update anaconda-navigator

> conda update navigator-updater

Библиотеки:

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
import cv2
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from os import listdir
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Flatten, Dropout, Dense
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
```

Остальной код:

```
print("[INFO] Загрузка модели...")
model = keras.models.load_model('cnn_vill.h5', custom_objects={'tf': tf})
# Show the model architecture
model.summary()
print("[INFO] Модель загружена...")

# Load labels
filename = 'plant_disease_label_transform.pkl'
image_labels = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))

# Dimension of resized image
DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE = tuple((256, 256))

def convert_image_to_array(image_dir):
    try:
        image = cv2.imread(image_dir)
        if image is not None:
            image = cv2.resize(image, DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE)   
            return img_to_array(image)
        else:
            return np.array([])
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error : {e}")
        return None

def predict_disease(image_path):
    image_array = convert_image_to_array(image_path)
    np_image = np.array(image_array, dtype=np.float16) / 225.0
    np_image = np.expand_dims(np_image,0)
    plt.imshow(plt.imread(image_path))
    result = model.predict_classes(np_image)
    print((image_labels.classes_[result][0]))
    
predict_disease(r'D:\PlantVillage\val\Corn_(maize)___Northern_Leaf_Blight\028159fc-995e-455a-8d60-6d377580a898___RS_NLB 4023.JPG')
predict_disease(r'D:\PlantVillage\val\Blueberry___healthy\008c85d0-a954-4127-bd26-861dc8a1e6ff___RS_HL 2431.JPG')
predict_disease(r'D:\PlantVillage\val\Potato___Early_blight\03b0d3c1-b5b0-48f4-98aa-f8904670290f___RS_Early.B 7051.JPG')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько способов добавить модуль в Anaconda.

```
conda install <package>

pip install <package>

python setup.py install
```

В вашем случае стоит попробовать эти команды:

```
conda install -c menpo opencv

conda install opencv

conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo opencv3
```

Comment: Пробовал все из вышеперечисленного, не помогло.

Comment: А тоже самое с opencv-python вместо opencv?

Answer (score 0):

Помогло создание новой виртуальной среды и повторная установка библиотек

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).